# Not requiring a password for user registration in MVC 3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I'm working on an application that only requires a username for registration and not a password. Down the road when the user creates a "full" account then we'll have them enter a password. Is this capability available in the .NET Membership model or would I need to roll my own solution? Obviously I would want to make the username unique.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done something similar when creating an MVC 3 site which allows users to login with their Facebook credentials.  If a new user comes along and choose to `Login with Facebook` I merely create a new acocunt for them, but don't get them to enter a password.

Ordinarily, if you use the standard .NET membership stuff, you do this (amongst other things) in the `Register` action:

```
MembershipCreateStatus createStatus = _membershipService.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email);
```

What I have elected to do is to generate some kind of random password (e.g. just generate a new `Guid` and `ToString()` it), like this:

```
model.Password = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Now we have the situation where the person has a password but *nobody in the world knows what it is*.  That doesn't matter for my case as they are logging in using Facebook.  However, if they want to ditch their Facebook connection, they can simply click on the `Forgotten Password` link and I'll generate a link which is emailed to them from which they can choose a new password, so all is well.

If you want to know how to create a new password without knowing the old one, this is how you can do it in the standard .NET membership provider:

```
   public bool ResetPassword(string userName, string newPassword)
    {
        try
        {
            MembershipUser user = _provider.GetUser(userName, true);
           // Create a new password and store it for a moment
           string resetPassword = user.ResetPassword();
           // Now set the new password, for which we need that new one we just generated...
           return user.ChangePassword(resetPassword, newPassword);           
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```